# .Net 6 App-Service won't connect to SQL in production

Tags: sql-server, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have several sites hosted on the same App Service Plan - an S1 instance. All are using the same set out Outbound IPs. I have a SQL server VM where all the databases live. I have a network security group with an inbound rule for the S1's outbound IPs.

All my other sites work perfectly and have access to the SQL VM and their respective databases.

The site in question works perfectly when hosted from my local dev machine, WITH the production database.

Yet I get an Access Denied error: "SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred...] when I promote it to production on Azure.

All the usual suspects (firewall, user doesn't exist, etc.) can be ruled out because ALL my other sites are using the same database server, credentials, and the only change in the connection string is the Initial Catalog. They are all on the same App Server and all have the same outbound IP so if one was getting blocked the others would be also. If it were a user problem, it wouldn't work when hosted locally.

The only difference between this and my other web apps is that this one is Blazor, built on .Net 6.  The others are on .Net Core 3.1 (LTS). I don't think that has any bearing since the  application in question, when hosted locally works with the production connection string. This IS the first time I've published a Blazor app and .Net 6 app, so...

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I can't figure out why this one site would act differently than the rest.

Could someone please offer up another avenue for me to pursue? Or, a way to get a more verbose error message from the failed connection? Anything to further my troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, I found my issue and it's unique to my project.

The truth, I separated the DAL from the presentation of the site. In the end, I was editing the wrong appsettings.json file.  For three hours.  *Face-palm*

My apologies if I wasted anyone's time.